# Using fieldset element to bundle inputs in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, forms, post

I'm working on a form with a lot of possible values in laravel.
I've made use of the fieldset element to bundle certain inputs and make it ever so slightly easier to disable inputs. I can do that by simply disabling the fieldset element but I can't seem to get back this or any other information about the fieldset element wrapping around certain inputs through laravel.

I've currently set up the name of the input with an array notation so that data is organized in a way I can iterate over it like so:

```php
<input type="number" name="input[items][{{$item->id}}][price]">
```

This implementation works like I want it to but it's repeated across many lines resulting in large blocks of repeated text which I'd like to condense where possible for both maintainability and readability.

My code that I'm trying to make work currently looks somewhat like this example:

```php
@foreach($list as $item)
<fieldset name="input[items][{{$item->id}}]">
    <input type="text" name="title">
    <input type="number" name="amount">
</fieldset>
@endforeach

<fieldset name="input[tasks][878]">
    <input type="text" name="...">
</fieldset>
```

I expect the data coming through to be in a format like this (ignore triple dots as placeholder)

```json
input: [
   items: [    
       321: {
           title: "product name"
           amount: 7
       },
       123: {
           title: "other product name"
           amount: 2
       } 
   ],
   tasks: [ 
      878: {
         ...
      } 
   ]
]
```

So my question is: Is the fieldset element even included in a POST request or is it purely for client side use? Is there a way I can make this work, by sending data about the fieldset along the inputs? The only thing I can think of without this possibility is making hidden inputs but that seems like the wrong way to do it.

There's some more information I found but it's not quite answering my question.

[HTML input arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010941/html-input-arrays)
[HTML Input name attribute as array - how to access values in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64744432/html-input-name-attribute-as-array-how-to-access-values-in-laravel)

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#flashing-input-then-redirecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`<fieldset>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset) is just a block level element used for logically grouping related elements together. It is useful for accessibility requirements, when used with the [`<legend>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/legend) element, but isn't actually included as part of a form submission.

As the `<input>` elements of your <`fieldset>` do not have unique `name` attributes, all that will happen with your implementation is any subsequent element(s) with the same `name` will override the value previously assigned to that `key` when the form is submitted (you may already have seen this if you've done some debugging etc.).

Rather than applying the `$item->id` key to the `<fieldset>`, apply it to the inputs instead:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>items</legend>
    @foreach($list as $item)
        <input type="text" name="items[{{ $item->id }}][title]" />
        <input type="number" name="items[{{ $item->id }}][amount]" />
    @endforeach
</fieldset>
```

The above will result in the following structure when accessed from your `$request` object (`dd($request->items);`):

```
^ array:2 [▼
  321 => array:2 [▼
    "title" => "product name"
    "amount" => "7"
  ]
  123 => array:2 [▼
    "title" => "other product name"
    "amount" => "2"
  ]
]
```

You can then apply the same principle to `tasks`.

Comment: I see, I was afraid fieldset was completely useless in the actual POST request. Currently I have unique names for each input like in my first example exactly like you suggested and I'll be able to work with this. I was trying to make it a little more condensed but it's not an issue. Thank you for confirming, marking this as answer.